# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buen dia, espero me puedan colaborar, estoy verificando si un email existe en la base de datos, con el fin de poder actualizar el email de un usuario evitando que el email ya este registrado.

**el error en pantalla es:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\MYFIP_1.0\funciones.php:95 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MYFIP_1.0\usuario.php(64):
>   emailExiste('stmendozza@hotm...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MYFIP_1.0\funciones.php on line 95

esta condicional esta en el archivo usuario.php ingresa a la funcion correctamente, ya valide que la variable email lleva el nuevo correo a registrar.

```
include "connections/config.php";
include ('funciones.php');

  if(emailExiste($email))
        {
            $errors_email[] = " El correo electronico $email ya existe en nuestra base de datos.";
        }
```

> 

Ya revise los campos : **usuario** y **email** en la base de datos,
la tabla de nombre **tb_usuarios** esta tal cual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> realice la consulta en la consola un par de veces y funciona, no se que pueda estar haciendo mal.

```
function emailExiste($email){
global $conexion;
$stmt= $conexion->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM tb_usuarios WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1 ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num= $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
if ($num > 0) 
{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código en sí parece correcto. Aquí lo más probable es que `$conexion` sea nulo y por eso falla. El uso de globales es una mala práctica. Supón que la conexión se cierra en cualquier parte, al ser global podrás controlar eso dificilmente.

Te propongo un código que controle esa eventualidad, y que controle también la ejecución, mostrando el motivo del error. Cuando hayas depurado puedes cambiar el mensaje de error por algo personalizado, pues no conviene mostrar mensajes internos del sistema al usuario.

```
function emailExiste($email){
    global $conexion;
    if ($conexion) 
    {
        $stmt= $conexion->prepare("SELECT usuario FROM tb_usuarios WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        if ( $stmt->execute() ) 
        {
            $stmt->store_result();
            $num= $stmt->num_rows;
            $stmt->close();
            if ($num > 0) 
            {
                return ["done"=>"Filas encontradas: $num"];
            } else {
                return ["error" => "No se encontraron filas"];
            }
        }else{
            return ["error"=>"Falló la ejecución de la consulta: {$stmt->error}"];
        }   
    }else{
            return ["error"=>"La conexión es nula. Revise su conexión"];
    }
}
```

Como podrás ver, he puesto otros `return` más, de modo que informen de lo que ocurre. El tipo de dato que se retorna ha cambiado, en vez de un booleano se devuelve un array con dos claves posibles: `done` o `error`. Entonces, donde recibes la respuesta debes cambiar para manejar y mostrar un mensaje adecuado si fuera preciso.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Llamada a la función
$resp=function emailExiste($email);

if (array_key_exists("done", $resp)) {
    #Se encontraron registros, hacer lo que haya que hacer
} else {
    #Imprimiremos el error
    echo $resp["error"];
}
```

Prueba de este modo. Si tienes alguna duda o problema lo dices en comentarios.

Comment: sigue saliendo el mismo error!, esta mañana funcionaba perfecto no se que hice para dañarlo, gracias

Comment: @STMENDOZZA no puede estar saliendo el mismo error. ¿Podrías decirme lo que muestra un `var_dump($resp);` si ejecutas el código como puse al final de la respuesta?

Comment: Ya me funciono tu respuesta gracias @A. Cedano.